# Run a task in the background of an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background

I want to be able to load data from my API server in the background of my iPhone app. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of options:

- Grand Central Dispatch
- `NSThread`
- `NSOperationQueue`
- Asynchronous network calls

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's an http based api, use the asynchronous methods of `NSURLConnection`. More information can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Otherwise you can use the async methods of NSOutputStream and NSInputStream with a CFSocket.

Comment: I second the use of NSURLConnection async methods.